# What happens if I disable AZRebalance and an AZ becomes unhealthy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, autoscaling

Curious about this quote:

> If you suspend AZRebalance and a scale out or scale in event occurs,
>   the scaling process still tries to balance the Availability Zones. For
>   example, during scale out, it launches the instance in the
>   Availability Zone with the fewest instances.

What happens if an AZ is unhealthy in this case? Will it still failover or will it still try to launch in that region because I've disabled AZRebalance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After certain actions occur, your Auto Scaling group can become unbalanced between Availability Zones. Auto Scaling compensates by rebalancing the Availability Zones.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/auto-scaling-benefits.html#AutoScalingBehavior.InstanceUsage

When an AZ is in an unhealthy state, or otherwise has no capacity, it isn't factored into the "unbalanced" calculation -- unbalanced refers to a condition where the workload isn't distributed evenly among healthy AZs with adequate capacity.

Note the word **after** in the quote.  In your scenario, `AZRebalance` refers something that happens after recovery, not during an event.

If an AZ is unhealthy, replacement instances will be launched in a different AZ, regardless of the setting.

Later, when the AZ returns to a healthy status, the system will try to migrate some of the instances back into the previously-unhealthy AZ to spread your workload back out... but without `AZRebalance`, the system won't try to even out the workload by launching new instances into the now-healthy AZ and then terminating some of the instances elsewhere -- it will just remain as it was, unbalanced, until other routine or recovery scaling events rebalance things over time.

Think of this as enabling a strictly proactive "best practice" rebalancing strategy that rebalances the instances just for the purpose of keeping the workload even across AZs -- which of course is where you want to be in a normal, healthy environment so that a subsequent problem will disrupt the minimum number of instances possible -- it does **not** impact the purposes of scaling in due to demand or to recover from the loss of some instances.  Disabling it doesn't impact those recovery actions.

Comment: So without AZRebalance it wont actively terminate and launch new instances to ensure balance. This has me a little confused though `until other routine or recovery scaling events rebalance things over time`, so you could you say without this feature, even though it could be unbalanced across AZs, it would never be _wildly_ unbalanced because AWS still tries to distribute the workload for NEW instances and still fails back over for recovered AZs?

Comment: It would remain wildly unbalanced until other scaling events caused it to move back toward balance, without this.  If you had 2 AZs with 5 each, then one was lost, so then you had 10 in a single AZ, it would just stay like that until it had scaled down and back up enough times for other reasons.  That's what this is for -- rebalancing proactively in the absence of other reasons.

Comment: but if that AZ comes back up it would try to migrate "some" of the instances to it right? Even if I had this feature enabled I would still be unbalanced until that region became healthy again right?